# how can i filter list from other list?

Tags: flutter, filter

how can i filter and get list of dog in secondData that have type; ['c1']
from  list cat from firstData that have id; 'c1'

must type; ['c1'] = id; 'c1'

simple code :

const firstData = [
Cat(
id;'c1',
title;'man')
];

const secondData = [
dog(
id;'m1',
type;['c1'],
title;'women')
];

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem

you just need to use where after your list

```
List<Cat> firstData = [Cat(id: 'c1', title: 'man')].toList();
List<Cat> check(String id) {
return firstData.where((cat) => cat.id==id).toList();
// or 
 return secondData .where((dog) => dog.type==id).toList();
}
```